# how to use 2 foreach in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

**how to use 2 foreach in laravel?**

The banner div cannot be included in the forach. Because the layout is broken.

```
//for show post 1-5
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    //.................
@endforeach

//for banner
<div>
...............
</div

//continue foreach (for show 6-...)
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    //.................
@endforeach
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your question but I think this might help https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#the-loop-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [loop variable](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#the-loop-variable), as like :

```
//for show post 1-5
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    @if($loop->index < 5)
        // Your code
    @endif
@endforeach

//continue foreach (for show 6-...)
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    @if($loop->index > 5)
        // Your code
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

You can break your posts data into 2 [chunks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-chunk) in blade

```
@foreach($posts->chunk(5) as $chunk)
        @foreach($chunk as $post)
            //.....
        @endforeach 
    //add your banner here after first chunk is rendered
@endforeach
```

Or a single loop and check for [current iteration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#the-loop-variable)

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    //...........
    @if($loop->iteration == 5)
        //add your banner here 
    @endif
@endforeach
```